# What is 'No Detent Torque'?

Tags: torque

I am learning about Variable Reluctance ( VR ) Stepper Motors.  As stated in my reference, they "have no detent torque."  What does this mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Detent torque is the torque while coils are not energised. Permanent magnets and the iron stator hold the motor in a given position without any power needing to be applied, although this force is usually much lower than the full torque - in my experience about 10%.